# How to switch languages inside T-SQL table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I need to switch between languages inside body of table-valued function to return month names and weekdays in different languages. But when I try to use `SET LANGUAGE RUSSIAN` I get `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET COMMAND' within a function.` error.

Why this happens while setting variables in TVF is OK? How can I change languages inside TVFs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `set language` inside a function.

What version are you on?

If 2012+ you could do

```
SELECT FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'dddd', 'ru-RU'), 
       FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'MMMM', 'ru-RU')
```

instead. (Returns `вторник, Сентябрь` at day of answering).

On previous versions you could write a CLR function that does similar.

Comment: Great, Martin! Thanks a lot! This suits me perfectly. I'm on 2014 btw.

Answer (score 3):

In versions prior to 2012 you could use the `sys.syslanguages` table to extract month names, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MonthNameByLanguage
AS
    WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
    Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2)
    SELECT  l.langid,
            languageName = l.name,
            l.alias,
            MonthNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l.[langid] ORDER BY n.Number),
            [MonthName] = SUBSTRING(l.months, n.Number, CHARINDEX(',', l.months + ',', n.Number) - n.Number)
    FROM    sys.syslanguages AS l
            INNER JOIN Numbers AS n
                ON (SUBSTRING(l.months, n.Number -1, 1) = ',' OR n.Number = 1);
```

This just takes the comma delimited month names from the system view and splits it out using a numbers table. Then you can use it inside your function as:

```
SELECT  MonthName
FROM    dbo.MonthNameByLanguage
WHERE   alias = 'RUSSIAN'
AND     MonthNumber = 3;
```

As a general rule though, I would do formatting as late as you can, just pass a date to your presentation layer, and let regional settings there handle formatting.

You can also do something similar for day names:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.DayNameByLanguage
AS
    WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
    Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2)
    SELECT  l.langid,
            languageName = l.name,
            l.alias,
            DayNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l.[langid] ORDER BY n.Number),
            [DayName] = SUBSTRING(l.days, n.Number, CHARINDEX(',', l.days + ',', n.Number) - n.Number)
    FROM    sys.syslanguages AS l
            INNER JOIN Numbers AS n
                ON (SUBSTRING(l.days, n.Number -1, 1) = ',' OR n.Number = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, Gareth, for answering! Looks like 2012+ made a huge progress to reduce amount of code.

Comment: No problem at all. I would describe my technique as a hack at best, it is using the system tables in SQL Server possibly not as they were intended. But yes, the introduction of the [`FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505.aspx) in 2012+, makes your life a lot easier in this case!